# How to access property in Polymer element from different element

Tags: javascript, polymer

How can I access a declared property of element `x-foo` from `x-bar`?

In my example I would like to access the title-property which lives inside `x-foo` from `x-bar`

JS Bin here: https://jsbin.com/muvidacoga/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have been doing is correct but you need to set the `title` property to notify when it is changed.

```
title : {
    type : String,
    notify: true, //set this
    value : "Hello World 1"
}
```

By setting the `notify` to true you tell the property to tell other elements that it has changed. That is called two-way data binding. Read more about two-way data binding from the polymer project website. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-notification

The way you access the property is good. On the demo I think you have just a small typo on the `//console.log(e).title;` line. It should be `//console.log(e.title);` So just on small fix.

With those changes and uncommenting the console.log. The console prints the `Hello World 1`.

EDIT:
If you are new to polymer 1.0 or polymer in general. I would suggest that you read trough or atleast skim trough the polymer-project.org developer guide and get started sections. That way you have some idea what info is displayed there and when you run into a problem you know if there is some info on that subject on the polymer website. It really helps in understanding polymer and helps in coding for polymer as you pick up some little bits every time you visit the site. :)